# About Discord Bot Event

Tags: java, bots, discord

```
if (messageSent.equalsIgnoreCase("is {0} my father")){
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("No! I am your father!").queue();
```

I wanna set that {0} entry in this "if" method for random words since it didn't worked. For example, if someone sent "is doe my father" or any word else, it will answer "No. I am your father!". Is there any solution for this?

Here's a code image of the class "HelloEvent.java" below:

[Image here...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCYoM.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please paste the code directly instead of linking an image.

Answer (score 0):

Use [MessageFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) for replacing `{0}`. Example:

> ```
> int planet = 7;
> String event = "a disturbance in the Force";
>
> String result = MessageFormat.format(
>  "At {1,time} on {1,date}, there was {2} on planet {0,number,integer}.",
>  planet, new Date(), event);
> ```